# Angular 12/Webpack is injecting css into my index.html after building instead of linking the scss file. This makes my global styles unusable

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

I am using Angular 12 with Webpack for use in a Chrome extension. When I build, for some reason Webpack is trying to inject my entire global css file into a  tag before the body. What should happen is it should simply link the associated stylesheet, but it isn't for some reason. Any ideas?

[My index.html file in my dist directory:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvTxX.png)